# jQuery UI Modal Dialog Overlay

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog

When a jQuery UI modal dialog is displayed everything under the modal window is grayed out - I assume that a partially transparent div covering the entire area of the window is used for this purpose.

In the app that I am creating the window has two main areas - the work area and a status bar at the bottom which I use, amongst other things,to show error messages.  The problem I have run into is this - if I display error messages from server side interactions initiated by the modal dialog they appear "dull".  Is there some way I could keep the semi transparent modal dialog overlay from covering the status bar at the bottom of the window so this does not happen?

I'd much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modal dialog creates a `div.ui-widget-overlay` that is set with high z-index. You simply have to set the `z-index` of your status bar to more, depending on how you initially create the dialogs.